# Determine the number of solutions of $x^{100} \equiv a\pmod{77}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have to determine the solution number of $x^{100} \equiv a\pmod{77}$ according to the value of $a$.

Inverse chinese remainder theorem:
$$
\begin{cases}
  x^{100} \equiv a\pmod{11}, \\
   x^{100} \equiv a\pmod{7} \\
\end{cases}
$$
Fermat's little theorem:
$$
\begin{cases}
  x^{10} \equiv a\pmod{11}, \\
   x^{4} \equiv a\pmod{7} \\
\end{cases}
$$
if $a = 0$, both have one solution, but how do I deduce the other solutions?

Comment: Use [this theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816731/proof-of-kth-power-theorem-xk-equiv-a-pmod-n-has-a-solution-iff-a-p?rq=1) with $\phi(n)=\phi(7)\phi(11)=60$. See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234689/proving-x-equiv-cd-modpq-is-a-solution-to-xe-equiv-c-modpq-whe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints**:

If $a\not\equiv 0\mod 11$, $x \not\equiv 0$ either, and by Fermat, $x^{10}\equiv 1$.

On the other hand, modulo $7$, it is straightforward to compute the possible values of $x^4$, if you write the nonzero values of $x$ as $\pm1,\pm 2,\pm 3$ and double-square them.

Comment: So, in the first case, if $a \equiv 1\;(mod\;11)$ do I have $2$ solutions?

Comment: Yes, since there are two solutions modulo $7$.